# Pie Chart's label overlapping to pie chart in small device

Tags: ios, swift, charts, pie-chart

I have used following library to display pie chart in my current project: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.

But, I'm facing an issue with pie chart in iPhone smaller devices. I have implemented following code to display pi chart:

```
class ChartVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pieChartView : PieChartView!

    var arrPiChartData : [PiChartData]?

    func setupPiChart() {

        let l = pieChartView.legend
        l.horizontalAlignment = .right
        l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
        l.orientation = .vertical
        l.xEntrySpace = 0
        l.yEntrySpace = 0
        l.yOffset = 0
        l.font = self.isPhone ? Typography.robotoRegular14 : Typography.robotoRegular18

        self.pieChartView.entryLabelFont = Typography.robotoRegular14
        self.pieChartView.drawHoleEnabled = false
        self.pieChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    func setupData() {

        var arr = [PieChartDataEntry]()

        if self.arrPiChartData != nil {

            for piChartData in self.arrPiChartData! {

                var name = ""
                if let strName = piChartData.name {
                    name = strName
                }

                var value = 0.0
                if let floatValue = piChartData.percentAmount {
                    value = Double(floatValue)
                }

                let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: value, label: name)
                arr.append(entry)
            }

            let set = PieChartDataSet(values: arr, label: "Total Sales by Company Users")
            set.drawIconsEnabled = false
            set.sliceSpace = 2
            set.xValuePosition = .outsideSlice
            set.entryLabelColor = UIColor.black
            set.entryLabelFont = self.isPhone ? Typography.robotoRegular14 : Typography.robotoRegular18

            set.colors = self.arrColours

            let data = PieChartData(dataSets: [set])

            let pFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            pFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
            pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
            pFormatter.multiplier = 1
            pFormatter.percentSymbol = " %"
            data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: pFormatter))

            self.pieChartView.data = data

        } else {
            self.pieChartView.data = nil
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupPiChart()
        self.setupData()
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.pieChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
    }
}
```

This code working to display pie chart. But there was an issue when I have run app in small device like iPhone SE, 5S, 6, 7, 8. There are label data overlapping to pie chart.

Please see following image which will describe what actual issue.

[image: Pie chart display issue in iPhone SE, 5S]

I have tried to find solution but didn't get.

I need help to fix this issue or better solution.

Comment: What about using the horizontal orientation? I think PieChart doesn't scale like other charts so you might need to set height explicitly for that iPhone size Or use horizontal orientation for legends.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce label font size in smaller devices?

Comment: If names are not finite you should not use pie chart here. Instead you can show the percentage by using bar chart.

Comment: @AnjiMendpara, Yes, I have tried it, but there will need to check for every single device to increase/decrease size programatically and its not good way.

Comment: @TheTiger, Names are dynamic. And my requirement to use pie chart.

Comment: @MayurKarmur Technically it can not be possible showing 100 users data into piechart without overlapping the labels. Just think you have only a circle and 0.4%, 0.5% data will make lines which might be less than 1px thick so in that case how would you show the titles? What most you can do is change the X positions of alternative title label so they will appear in zig zag pattern.

Comment: @TheTiger, You are right. I think, showing title in pie chart is not good. I will remove it.

Comment: @Kamran, Your point is absolutely correct. I hope there will not more than 30 data.

Comment: @Kamran, I'm trying to display legends with horizontal direction and remove title from pie chart. I will show my output.

Comment: As @TheTiger said, it's better to use other chart if you have more 5-10 entries. 6 degree angle is not as visible as 6 pixels on Bar chart. And if you are showing legends then you can disable showing `valueLinePart/xAxisLabels`.

Comment: @Kamran, From your and **TheTiger's** suggestions, I have updated my code, See my answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: Regarding % display in pie chart, there aren't an issue, because that we can't manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to there aren't good way to display more legends vertically in pie chart, I have updated my code to display it in horizontal direction. Also title is not display properly in pie chart so remove it. For that I have updated my code as follows to display proper pie chart:

```
func setupPiChart() {

    // This will align label text to top right corner
    let l = pieChartView.legend
    l.horizontalAlignment = .left
    l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
    l.orientation = .horizontal
    l.xEntrySpace = 10
    l.yEntrySpace = 0
    l.font = self.isPhone ? Typography.robotoRegular14 : Typography.robotoRegular18

    self.pieChartView.entryLabelFont = Typography.robotoRegular14
    self.pieChartView.drawHoleEnabled = false
    self.pieChartView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
    self.pieChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Now, it's display good as looks in following image:

[image: Pie chart legends display horizontally]